# When exactly does onShouldSendPushData() fire?

Tags: sinch

I've set up a chat app with Parse + Sinch (I used [this official tutorial](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/) mostly) and I'm trying to get notifications to work in a particular way:

1. When the MessagingActivity is opened, the receiver of the message
   **shouldn't** get any notifications.
2. When the home button is pressed and the app is "minimised" but not
   closed (The activities have not yet been destroyed), the receiver
   **should** get a notification.

Currently, the receiver only gets a notification when the app is completely closed (swiped away from the multitasking view) and the Activity that started the MessageService has been destroyed.

Is onShouldSendPushData() only called when the app is closed completely?
Is there anyway I can achieve my goal to make it call whenever the app is in the backstack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onShouldSendPushNotification` is only called if the other device does not acknowledge that the message has been received within a few seconds from the time the message was sent. If you call `stopListeningOnActiveConnection` whenever your activity is no longer the active activity, and then `startListeningOnActiveConnection` when your activity is active you should see the behavior you desire.